# What does 'unregistered' mean on user profiles?

Tags: discussion

This is something I first noticed in users who posted spam. They would make a post, I would click their profile, and it would come up (unregistered). At first I thought it was their account being deleted by moderators, but I'm beginning to notice it in other non-spamming first time users as well. Is this a result of people not having to make an account to ask a question, or do these people really not want a Chem.SE account?

Comment: When a user is deleted/ destroyed you cannot click the profile any more. It simply does not exist and the posts, which have been created by this account are anonymised. If you happen to have the link to such a user profile, you will only get the info about the destruction.

Comment: @Mart ? I don't think this is about what you think it is.

Comment: @PhMgBr You obviously did not pay much attention to the whole post. I am clarifying `I thought it was their account being deleted by moderators`.

Comment: Ahh @Mart. Time to reread SE 101 textbooks. :P BTW I didn't know this myself until I stumped upon that request thingy linked in my answer. This isn't reasonably documented anywhere as far as my searches are concerned.

Comment: [What does it mean to be unregistered?](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2489/27052)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

'Unregistered' means they're not a user yet.

For people with first posts, there's this option called 'post as guest'. They can post a question without having to log in, and their account is only identified by a browser cookie. Accounts made this way are **unregistered** accounts. There are some problems with this method, but it makes posting much, much easier for new users.

There's a [meta.SE proposal](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/243712/post-as-guest-is-a-bad-user-experience-and-encourages-low-quality-contribution) to get rid of it, without any official results.